# Yahoo App Authentication Laravel

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-5, yahoo-api

**i am using this library** 
https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

**here is my code**

```
public function loginWithYahoo() {
   // get data from input
    $token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
    $verify = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );
    // get yahoo service
    $yh = OAuth::consumer( 'Yahoo' );

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( !empty( $token ) && !empty( $verify ) ) {
                // This was a callback request from yahoo, get the token
                $token = $yh->requestAccessToken( $token, $verify );
                $xid = array($token->getExtraParams());
                $result = json_decode( $yh->request( 'https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/'.$xid[0]['xoauth_yahoo_guid'].'/profile?format=json' ), true ); 

                dd($result);                                
    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else {
        // get request token
        $reqToken = $yh->requestRequestToken();
        // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
        $url = $yh->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));
        // return to yahoo login url
        return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}.
```

I am getting following error.. can any one please give some hint???Thanks in advance
Call to undefined method OAuth\OAuth2\Service\Yahoo::requestRequestToken()

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$url = $yh->getAuthorizationUri();
return redirect((string)$url);
```

instead of this code:

```
// get request token
$reqToken = $yh->requestRequestToken();
// get Authorization Uri sending the request token
$url = $yh->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));
// return to yahoo login url
return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
```

Comment: You should include *why* this helps.